# Data storage for a catalog app on Firebase - which storage type should you choose?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I continue to write my first application - a catalog in which a user selects spare parts from different categories and adds them to the basket for subsequent ordering.
Ex. of my catalogue in realtime database :

```
[{
"nameOfSection": "partsForCars",
"imageOfSection": "some url",
"cars": [{
        "nameOfSection": "Toyota",
        "imageOfSection": "some url",
        "units": [{
            "nameOfUnit": "Engine",
            "imageOfSection": "some url",
            "spareParts": [{
                "nameOfSparePart": "Piston",
                "costOfSparePart": "100$",
                "imageOfSparePart": "some url"}]},
            {"nameOfSection": "body",
            "imageOfSection": "some url",
            "spareParts": [{
                "nameOfPart": "Hood",
                "costOfPart": "200",
                "imageOfPart": "some url"
}]}]}]}]
```

When I launch the application, I extract the json and create a tableview with transitions in the nesting of the directory. Then the user adds the necessary spare part to the cart, which I want to store in Firebase as well.

Question: how to store the cart? Create a new link "Users / someId / shoppingCart" in the same realtime database and add the selected object there? In this case, I duplicate the entry for the object - now it exists both in the catalog and in the shopping cart. What is the best way to implement such functionality?
Thanks!

Comment: You're not duplicating the entire car, just adding the spare parts to your user's cart. It's pretty common in NoSQL to duplicate pieces of data in many locations

Comment: In this case i duplicate spare part (Piston, for ex.) : now it would be in catalogue ( "cars": [{
        "nameOfSection": "Toyota",
        "imageOfSection": "some url",
        "units": [{
            "nameOfUnit": "Engine",
            "imageOfSection": "some url",
            "spareParts": [{
                "nameOfSparePart": "Piston",
                "costOfSparePart": "100$",
                "imageOfSparePart": "some url"},

Comment: And in user shopping cart:                                                                                    "users": {
"someID": {
"order": [{"nameOfSparePart": "Piston",
           "costOfSparePart": "100$",
           "imageOfSparePart": "some url"
}]}}}

Comment: Two identical objects in different places - is this correct?

Comment: Yes, in the scenario you described you would be duplicating the data in 2 spots. As you're storing large amounts of data that appears to be semi structured it may be a better fit to use Firestore for your application as it would allow you to perform more complex querying.